# Is there a package called document_base?

Tags: python-3.x, pip, pytorch, google-colaboratory, yolo

I tried to implement YOLOv3 using PyTorch and I found that models had changed to doqu and I changed it accordingly. What I got next was this

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'document_base'

When I tried to install it with pip however I got this

> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement document_base (from versions: none)
>
> ERROR: No matching distribution found for document_base

Is there a way to install this or are there any workarounds to this??

Answer (score 0):

It's a module inside `doqu`: https://bitbucket.org/neithere/doqu/src/default/doqu/document_base.py

To import it:

```
import doqu.document_base
```

or

```
from doqu import document_base
```

Comment: When I took a look at the __init__.py in doqu document_base was present. Is that an issue itself because that is where my error was

Comment: Oh, you mean [this line](https://bitbucket.org/neithere/doqu/src/df322d597d540b0f7349fe761c7e8379d1eff4b2/doqu/__init__.py#lines-21)? Yes, seems like a bug in `doqu` or more precisely, like a code written for Python 2.

Comment: Yes, that very line. So is there a workaround or there's nothing that can be done?

Comment: Install it and fix `__init__.py`. Send a bug report or pull request.